# suggestion not displaying android

Tags: android, android-listview, android-sqlite

I got this problem with the displaying of the item returned by the custom ContentProvider that I have made....The following is the custom content Provider (SolutionProvider.java):

```
package pioperation.tregliapi.computercomesifa;
import java.util.HashMap;
import android.content.ContentProvider;
import android.content.ContentUris;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.UriMatcher;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQueryBuilder;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.text.TextUtils;

public class SolutionProvider extends ContentProvider {

    static final String PROVIDER_NAME = "pioperation.tregliapi.computercomesifa.SolutionProvider";
    static final String URL = "content://" + PROVIDER_NAME + "/solutions";
    static final Uri CONTENT_URI = Uri.parse(URL);

    static final String _ID = "_id";
    static final String NAME = "name";
    static final String SHORT_DESCRIPTION = "short_description";
    static final String IMAGE_SMALL = "imageSmall";

    private static HashMap<String, String> SOLUTIONS_PROJECTION_MAP;

    static final int SOLUTIONS = 1;
    static final int SOLUTION_ID = 2;

    static final UriMatcher uriMatcher;
    static{
        uriMatcher = new UriMatcher(UriMatcher.NO_MATCH);
        uriMatcher.addURI(PROVIDER_NAME, "solutions", SOLUTIONS);
        uriMatcher.addURI(PROVIDER_NAME, "students/#", SOLUTION_ID);
    }

    /**
     * Database specific constant declarations
     */
    private SQLiteDatabase db;
    static final String DATABASE_NAME = "Solutions";
    static final String SOLUTIONS_TABLE_NAME = "solutions";
    static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    static final String CREATE_DB_TABLE =
            " CREATE TABLE " + SOLUTIONS_TABLE_NAME +
                    " (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
                      NAME + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
                    SHORT_DESCRIPTION +" TEXT NOT NULL, " +
                    IMAGE_SMALL +" TEXT NOT NULL );";

    /**
     * Helper class that actually creates and manages
     * the provider's underlying data repository.
     */
    private static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
        DatabaseHelper(Context context){
            super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db)
        {
            db.execSQL(CREATE_DB_TABLE);
        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion,
                              int newVersion) {
            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " +  SOLUTIONS_TABLE_NAME);
            onCreate(db);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreate() {
        Context context = getContext();
        DatabaseHelper dbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(context);
        /**
         * Create a write able database which will trigger its
         * creation if it doesn't already exist.
         */
        db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        System.out.print("il valore di DB è: " + db);
        return (db == null)? false:true;
    }

    @Override
    public Uri insert(Uri uri, ContentValues values) {
        /**
         * Add a new solution record
         */
        long rowID = db.insert( SOLUTIONS_TABLE_NAME, "", values);

        /**
         * If record is added successfully
         */
        if (rowID > 0)
        {
            Uri _uri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(CONTENT_URI, rowID);
            getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(_uri, null);
            return _uri;
        }
        throw new SQLException("Failed to add a record into " + uri);
    }

    @Override
    public Cursor query(Uri uri, String[] projection, String selection,
                        String[] selectionArgs, String sortOrder) {

        SQLiteQueryBuilder qb = new SQLiteQueryBuilder();
        qb.setTables(SOLUTIONS_TABLE_NAME);
        String query = uri.getLastPathSegment().toLowerCase();
        /*
        switch (uriMatcher.match(uri)) {
            case SOLUTIONS:
                qb.setProjectionMap(SOLUTIONS_PROJECTION_MAP);
                break;
            case SOLUTION_ID:
                qb.appendWhere( _ID + "=" + uri.getPathSegments().get(1));
                break;
            default:
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown URI " + uri);
        }
        if (sortOrder == null || sortOrder == ""){
            /**
             * By default sort on student names

            sortOrder = NAME;
      //  }
    */


        Cursor c = qb.query(db, projection, selection, selectionArgs,
                null, null, null);
        /**
         * register to watch a content URI for changes
         */
        c.setNotificationUri(getContext().getContentResolver(), uri);
        int totalRow = c.getCount();
      //  return c;
        return c;

    }

    @Override
    public int delete(Uri uri, String selection, String[] selectionArgs) {
        int count = 0;

        switch (uriMatcher.match(uri)){
            case SOLUTIONS:
                count = db.delete(SOLUTIONS_TABLE_NAME, selection, selectionArgs);
                break;
            case SOLUTION_ID:
                String id = uri.getPathSegments().get(1);
                count = db.delete( SOLUTIONS_TABLE_NAME, _ID +  " = " + id +
                        (!TextUtils.isEmpty(selection) ? " AND (" +
                                selection + ')' : ""), selectionArgs);
                break;
            default:
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown URI " + uri);
        }

        getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(uri, null);
        return count;
    }

    @Override
    public int update(Uri uri, ContentValues values, String selection,
                      String[] selectionArgs) {
        int count = 0;

        switch (uriMatcher.match(uri)){
            case SOLUTIONS:
                count = db.update(SOLUTIONS_TABLE_NAME, values,
                        selection, selectionArgs);
                break;
            case SOLUTION_ID:
                count = db.update(SOLUTIONS_TABLE_NAME, values, _ID +
                        " = " + uri.getPathSegments().get(1) +
                        (!TextUtils.isEmpty(selection) ? " AND (" +
                                selection + ')' : ""), selectionArgs);
                break;
            default:
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown URI " + uri );
        }
        getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(uri, null);
        return count;
    }

    @Override
    public String getType(Uri uri) {
        switch (uriMatcher.match(uri)){
            /**
             * Get all solution records
             */
            case SOLUTIONS:
                return "vnd.android.cursor.dir/vnd.example.students";
            /**
             * Get a particular student
             */
            case SOLUTION_ID:
                return "vnd.android.cursor.item/vnd.example.students";
            default:
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unsupported URI: " + uri);
        }
    }
}
```

when I do the query from a SearchDialog I correctly enter and execute the query() method, and I've seen that the cursor returned by the query method has 9 items in it....So it is actually populated with informations. The problem is that I cannot see the values in the eventual ListView of the SearchDialog!!!

THe following is the `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="pioperation.tregliapi.computercomesifa" >

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainPage"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>

        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".SearchItem"
            android:label="Cerca il problema"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme">


            <meta-data android:name="android.app.default_searchable"
                android:value=".SearchBackend" />

        </activity>

        <activity android:name=".SearchBackend"
            android:label="Cerca il problema">

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name ="android.intent.action.SEARCH" />
            </intent-filter>

            <meta-data android:name="android.app.searchable"
                android:resource="@xml/searchable"/>
        </activity>

        <provider android:name="pioperation.tregliapi.computercomesifa.SolutionProvider"
            android:authorities="pioperation.tregliapi.computercomesifa.SolutionProvider"
           >
        </provider>

        <activity android:name=".VisualizeItem"
            android:label="Visualizza le soluzioni presenti"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Thanks in advance for your help!!!

EDIT: ok with the debug I've noticed that inside the SolutionProvider there's this snippet:

```
                                //mSearchView.getWindow().getDecorView().post(mStartSpinnerRunnable); // TODO:
    try {
        cursor = mSearchManager.getSuggestions(mSearchable, query, QUERY_LIMIT);
        // trigger fill window so the spinner stays up until the results are copied over and
        // closer to being ready
        if (cursor != null) {
            cursor.getCount();
            return cursor;
        }
    } catch (RuntimeException e) {
        Log.w(LOG_TAG, "Search suggestions query threw an exception.", e);
    }
    // If cursor is null or an exception was thrown, stop the spinner and return null.
    // changeCursor doesn't get called if cursor is null
    // mSearchView.getWindow().getDecorView().post(mStopSpinnerRunnable); // TODO:
    return null;
}
```

and I don't know why but he can do the getCount() call, the cursor is not null, but somehow he doesn't return the the cursor, but he gets out and return null......Any suggestion?

EDIT:
Ok I finally figured out what was wrong: I did the query but I wasn't passing the Projection Map (the HashMap) inside the query (actually I was passing an empty one)...So actually the query was working fine but the cursor didn't have the right structure so it wasn't possible to display it... Maybe someone with the same problem will benefit this post!

Comment: post the code of `SearchDialog` where you are displaying data.

Comment: I didn't display the cursor! Teorically the only thing that I should do is to return the cursor so AUTOMATICALLY it will be displayed as a ListView....Am I wrong?

Comment: Ok so I was trying to figure out why the suggestions won't show up and I noticed that I didn't actually use the URI matcher (in the query method I just take all the result....); could this be an issue? What do youi think about?